# how to initialize vector in function parameter

Tags: c++, syntax

as my topic only defines the question. try to understand with code what I am trying to do but getting error in vector part in parameter section of the function

```
void recursion(vector<int>vec{2,4,5},int n=0)
{
     if(n==3)
     {
         return;
     }
     cout<<vec[n];
     recursion(vec,n+1)        
}
```

Comment: `void recursion(vector<int>vec={2,4,5},int n=0)`

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Do you want to pass a default vector if none is used?

Comment: Also note that your function can easily be abused. If you really need a recursive solution then consider using a lambda that calls itself recursively and define it locally inside the function, and let the function take only the vector argument (by `const` reference!). That way you won't risk out of bounds behavior or bad recursions because the caller used bad arguments.